# How to perform operation between different columns after groupby a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am not sure what I did, but I was expecting the same result for these two methods to calculate the hitting average for the baseball players from Lahmans Baseball dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

batting = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/bhishanpdl/Datasets/blob/master/Lahman_batting.csv?raw=true')

# create new col
batting['ba'] = batting['H'] / batting['AB']

# groupby for each baseball player
print(batting.groupby('playerID')[['ba','AB']]
             .sum().head().reset_index())
```

This gives:

```
    playerID        ba     AB
0  aardsda01  0.000000      4
1  aaronha01  6.924731  12364
2  aaronto01  1.544619    944
3   aasedo01  0.000000      5
4   abadan01  0.117647     21
```

But, looking at only second player, the result is wrong.

```
# sanity check for aaronha01
a = batting.query(""" playerID == 'aaronha01'  """)['H'].sum()
b = batting.query(""" playerID == 'aaronha01'  """)['AB'].sum()
a,b,a/b
(3771, 12364, 0.30499838240051763)
```

How to correct the result?

For the second player called `aaronha01`, the result should be `0.30499838240051763` but groupby gives `6.924731`.

**Update**
In R we get the correct, but I was looking the way in Pandas:

```
library(Lahman)

batting = as_tibble(Lahman::Batting)
batters = batting  %>%  
    group_by(playerID) %>%  
    summarize(
      ba = sum(H, na.rm = TRUE) / sum(AB, na.rm = TRUE),
      ab = sum(AB, na.rm = TRUE)
    )

head(batters)

playerID    ba  ab
aardsda01   0.0000000   4
aaronha01   0.3049984   12364
aaronto01   0.2288136   944
aasedo01    0.0000000   5
abadan01    0.0952381   21
abadfe01    0.1111111   9
```

Comment: @ALollz Thanks for info, but would please help solving the problem using groupby, Wanted value for second player is 0.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sum both columns, then calculate the average after the groupby:

```
gp = batting.groupby('playerID')[['H', 'AB']].sum()
gp['ba'] = gp.H/gp.AB
print(gp)

#              H     AB        ba
#playerID                        
#aardsda01     0      4  0.000000
#aaronha01  3771  12364  0.304998
#aaronto01   216    944  0.228814
#aasedo01      0      5  0.000000
#abadan01      2     21  0.095238
#abadfe01      1      9  0.111111
#abadijo01    11     49  0.224490
```

If you want it to all be on one line can chain with `eval`:

```
batting.groupby('playerID')[['H', 'AB']].sum().eval('ab = H / AB')
```

---

To explain your original issue, the above is a batting average where each AB is given the same weight. In your original formulation, by first calculating a `'ba'` for each row and then taking the average, you are giving equal weight to each observation (in this case basically each year) instead of each individual at bat. Had you weighted that average by the number of ABs in each row you'd arrive at the same answer as above.

Comment: Thanks, If my dataset is larger than `15k` rows I like to use `eval and query` in pandas, otherwise they are slightly slower.